# Add background gradient colouring in a table using matplotlib

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a dataframe that I want to export as an image, but I also want to colour the cells based on the values
I achieved it using dataframe_image: [dataframe_image result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WCbU.png)

but now I need to get the same result using **matplotlib**.
so far I managed to render a table using the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['One','Two','Three','Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten','Eleven'],
                         '1Param': [255,191,1200,130,474,22,1203,1618,959,45,6097],
                         '2Param': [21,27,173,16,43,0,181,151,107,7,726],
                         '3Param': [2022,1794,9045,1054,3642,152,8431,12411,6630,325,45506],
                         '4Param': [470,486,2230,252,1092,18,2008,2748,1364,86,10754],
                             })
    

def render_mpl_table(data, col_width=3.0, row_height=0.625, font_size=14,
                     header_color='#40466e', row_colors=['#f1f1f2', 'w'], edge_color='w',
                     bbox=[0, 0, 1, 1], header_columns=0,
                     ax=None, **kwargs):
    if ax is None:
        size = (np.array(data.shape[::-1]) + np.array([0, 1])) * np.array([col_width, row_height])
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=size)
        ax.axis('off')

    mpl_table = ax.table(cellText=data.values, bbox=bbox, colLabels=data.columns, **kwargs)
    
    mpl_table.auto_set_font_size(False)
    mpl_table.set_fontsize(font_size)
    mpl_table.auto_set_column_width(col=list(range(len(data.columns))))  
    
    for k, cell in  six.iteritems(mpl_table._cells):
        cell.set_edgecolor(edge_color)
        if k[0] == 0 or k[1] < header_columns:
            cell.set_text_props(weight='bold', color='w')
            cell.set_facecolor(header_color)
        # else:
        #     cell.set_facecolor(row_colors[k[0]%len(row_colors)])      

    return ax

render_mpl_table(df, header_columns=0)
```

the result I get: [matplotlib result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wm9bW.png)
does anyone know how do I add background gradient colouring similar to dataframe_image module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a color map that is close to the expected output and standardize on the maximum and minimum values of the data. Looping to get the cell's string, and if the string is not an error when converted to float, it is numeric, so the value is used to set the color in the cell.

```
def render_mpl_table(data, col_width=3.0, row_height=0.625, font_size=14,
                     header_color='#40466e', row_colors=['#f1f1f2', 'w'], edge_color='w',
                     bbox=[0, 0, 1, 1], header_columns=0,
                     ax=None, **kwargs):
    if ax is None:
        size = (np.array(data.shape[::-1]) + np.array([0, 1])) * np.array([col_width, row_height])
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=size)
        ax.axis('off')

    # min, max
    min_val = df[['1Param', '2Param', '3Param', '4Param']].min().min()
    max_val = df[['1Param', '2Param', '3Param', '4Param']].max().max()
    # normalize and cmap
    norm = plt.Normalize(vmin=min_val, vmax=max_val)
    cmap = plt.get_cmap('Blues')
    
    mpl_table = ax.table(cellText=data.values, bbox=bbox, colLabels=data.columns, **kwargs)

    mpl_table.auto_set_font_size(False)
    mpl_table.set_fontsize(font_size)
    mpl_table.auto_set_column_width(col=list(range(len(data.columns))))  

    for k, cell in  six.iteritems(mpl_table._cells):
        cell.set_edgecolor(edge_color)
        if k[0] == 0 or k[1] < header_columns:
            cell.set_text_props(weight='bold', color='w')
            cell.set_facecolor(header_color)
        else:
            v = cell._text.get_text()
            #print(type(v))
            try:
                float(v)
            except ValueError:
                pass
            else:
                #print(v)
                cell.set_facecolor(cmap(norm(int(v))))      

    return ax

render_mpl_table(df, header_columns=0)
```

[image]

Comment: hi! thanks for your answer, but maybe you know how to do the colouring on every column separately?

Comment: Since one colormap was used for the entire value, it is possible to use a colormap for each column in the same way, using the maximum and minimum values for each.

Comment: If I understand correctly `for k, cell in  six.iteritems(mpl_table._cells):` iterates trough cells horizontally (row by row). do you know a way to iterate trough cells vertically so I can colour column by column?

Comment: It is necessary to capture the counter k and determine the column. For example, the counter of k in the column 1Param is [1,6,11,16,21,26...]. and you judge by that.

Comment: You would have made it work. Please review the following information.[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)